# Display Progress bar when writing data into textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox, progress-bar

I have to write a long text to a textbox, the screen freezing a long time.
So I want to display progress bar when writing text to textbox. Any suggestion with my code? Thank you!

```
private void btnCheckProcStep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                txtResults.Clear();
                DataTable dtx = new DataTable();             
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdMametanCheckList.Rows)
                {
                    var _MAMETAN_NO = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    dtx = get_Missing_Proc_Inst_Seq(_MAMETAN_NO);
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dtx.Rows)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()+ ","+ dr[0].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
                    }                   
                }   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }            
        }
```

Comment: You are doing it server side, it's a  front-end feature!

Comment: Do not use string + string in a cycle. Replace it with `StringBuilder` and it will be much faster.

Comment: It is Windows Form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use BackgroundWorker to aysnc process

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }
    void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Your background task goes here
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            SetText(i.ToString()+" %");
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MEssagebox");
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** : Need to run progress bar continue when data is retrieving from database and writing to textbox.

Comment: Thanks, but In my case how can I use your code. It is Windows Form

Comment: off-course its also a windows form code
  // Your background task goes here
In this section you can use your database query and execute code

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate how many times you would need to add to your progress before in equals full (set to 100 or your to you choice, its known as the Maximum value). I would do this by Progress Bar changes needed would be 100 (or Maximum) divided by the amount of Rows in your DataRow.

```
ProgBarChange = progBar.Maximum / DataRow.Count()
```

Then inside your Foreach I would increase your progressbar using this ProgBarChange value.

```
progBar.Value += ProgBarChange;
```

Remember to clear the progBar just like you have done with your txtResults.Clear().

```
progBar.Value = 0;
```

Comment: And how does this answer his question?

Comment: Oh I thought I seen the #wpf tag.. yes we would need to see what he is using

Comment: I am using Windows Form

Answer (score 0):

You should use BackgroundWorker for updating progress.

Answer (score 0):

It is a client side feature. If possible try the below simple java script progress bar.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #ProgressBar {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ddd;
        }
        #Bar {
            width: 1%;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #4CAF50;
        }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function showProgress() {
            var element = document.getElementById("Bar");
            var width = 1;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= 100) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    width++;
                    element.style.width = width / 2 + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ProgressBar">
        <div id="Bar"></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="txtResults" onkeypress="showProgress()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Windows Form please!